# Android, how to auto adjust the item's vertical position in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android-constraintlayout

Having a ConstraintLayout with mainly left and right part.
Right side has fixed content.
Left side contains a few items vertically, and some of them dynamically show/hide.

Wold like the left side are always vertically centered, like
when only AAA, CCC are visible:

```
----------------  -----------------
|              | |                |
|              | |                |
|              | |                |
| AAA          | |                |
|              | |                |
| CCCC         | |                |
|              | |                |
|              | |                |
|              | |                |
-----------------------------------
```

when some ddd, BBB, BBB are visible

```
----------------  -----------------
|              | |                |
| AAA          | |                |
|              | |                |
| AAA          | |                |
|              | |                |
| BBB          | |                |
|              | |                |
| CCC          | |                |
|              | |                |
-----------------------------------
```

Made one but could not do the vertical center, how to make it not fix top/bottom aligned and all extra height space should distributed above and below:

[image] -->  [image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/_container"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_goneMarginEnd="0dp"
        app:layout_goneMarginStart="0dp"
        tools:text="title: lone test test test test test test test test test" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/_rating"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/_cta"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.07"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.79"
        tools:background="#ff0000"

        tools:visibility="gone"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/_cta"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/_rating"

        android:maxLines="1"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"

        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#770000ff"
        app:strokeColor="#770000ff"

        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"

        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"

        android:text="Install It"
        tools:visibility="gone"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/_text"
        style="@style/doublePlay.textRegular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"

        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="The Compmany"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/_cta"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/_icon"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:src="#ff00ff"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/_text" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/_name"
        style="@style/doublePlay.textRegular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/_text"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/_icon"
        tools:text="The Interest long long long long long" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/_container"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="114dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@color/black"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:src="@color/blue"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/_video"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the widgets in a vertical chain with a chain style of `packed`. Now when a widget is set to `gone`, the other widgets will redistribute themselves. Here is an example:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="AAAA"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="BBBB"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="CCCC"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="DDDD"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

All widgets set to visible:

[image]

Widgets "BBBB" and "DDDD" set to `gone`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting constraint for each widget on your layout's left side. Put all this inside a `LinearLayout` set its `android:orientation="vertical"` and `"android:gravity="start"`. (You can try other value for gravity to suit your need). And finally set the constraint for this `LinearLayout` alone. To parent top and bottom to be vertically aligned. and start to parent end to right frame as you would.

As an example I made a sample one from your xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/top_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/_container"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            tools:text="title: lone test test test test test test test test test" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/_rating"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            tools:background="#ff0000" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/_cta"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:insetTop="0dp"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Install It"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#770000ff"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            app:cornerRadius="20dp"
            app:strokeColor="#770000ff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/_text"
            style="@style/doublePlay.textRegular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="The Compmany"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/_icon"
            android:layout_width="14dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:src="#ff00ff" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/_name"
            style="@style/doublePlay.textRegular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            tools:text="The Interest long long long long long" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/_container"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="114dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@color/black" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:src="@color/blue"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/_video"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Try and see if this helps you achieve what you want.